# Reloading implicit dependencies in Development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a Rails application with an embedded DSL for defining customizable but long-lived data structures. To this end I created a directory under /app where some less technical team members can edit the data structures which look similar to this:

```
Repository.define do
  item :important do
    cost 30
    depends_on :even_more_important
    # further config
  end
end
```

These files are loaded using an initializer which saves creates the data structure in the Repository class:

```
class Repository
  def self.item(name, &block)
    @items[name] = Item.new(name, &block)
  end
end
```

In development mode the Repository class is reloaded on every request, clearing the items array every time.

So how can I:

1. Prevent the reloading of the Repository class
2. Or even better reload the files in the items directory **after** the reloading of the Repository class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two options:

1. Don't reload your class by moving it to `Dependencies.load_once_paths` (or add your path to `load_once_paths`, it shouldn't be `app/models` though). You will need to restart server to update DSL in development mode.
2. Add your initialization at the bottom of your `repository.rb` after class declaration (something like `load "your_dsl_path_name"`).

My first idea with `config/environment.rb` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By design, in Rails, every request should be considered independent, and you should not use class variables to persist anything. Even if you disable reloading in development, there is no guarantee that a process will persist even in production. Many deployments (like Heroku) use a distributed process model, so your `@items` class variable won't be consistent across requests.

I highly recommend that you persist that data elsewhere, like the database or a persistent key-value store like Memcached.

Still if you want to keep rails from reloading your class, just override the `reloadable?` class method:

```
def self.reloadable?
  false
end
```

Comment: How about config options? They are read from source tree, consistent accross requests and IMO this is what @derfred wants (and they are stored in class variables).

Comment: Rails configuration is just that: Configuration. Those don't change between requests so even if the server restarts, the reloaded options are the same.

Comment: The data structures are static. In production they dont change, but I want the dev team to have the same feature as with the templates which you can edit in Development mode without restarting the server.